# bat/cmd file does not return back

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7, directory

I want to launch some .cmd file and to remain in the same directory.

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\wl_server\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd
```

The problem is that while executing the setDomainEnv.cmd wit about 10 other cmd files called from it, I am left in totally another directory. And I want to be where I have started. As I always start in the same directory, I am adding a cd line:

```
Echo on
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\wl_server\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd
Echo on
cd /d C:\workspaces\DS8\swprods\dist-4.1.8-local-devel\
```

No effect! Again I am left in

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\wl_server>
```

And I never even see the 3,4 lines to appear in the console. I could understand all that if some of the inner skripts ended with error, but they finish OK, without errors.

It would be understandable if some of the scripts changed the dir to another disk and back change would need /d key. But all is done on the same C: disk.

All operations in the script are conducted in the same source directory. The directory is changed after leaving the batch file.

```
....................................................
C:\workspaces\DS8\swprods\dist-4.1.8-local-devel>if "Oracle" == "Apple" (set MEM
_ARGS=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m  -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m )

C:\workspaces\DS8\swprods\dist-4.1.8-local-devel>if exist C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\WL_SER~1\bin\setStartupEnv.cmd (call "C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\WL_SER~1\bin\setStartupEnv.cmd" )
^this is the last run line of the script
```

"Why?" and sometimes I thought, "Wherefore?" and sometimes I thought, "Inasmuch as which? And how can I change the directory back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html):

```
call C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\wl_server\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd
```

Call will invoke another script and after it gets completed - it will returns to your script.

If you do not use `call` - your execution flow goes to that another script but does not return back.

Comment: Oh! without call it does not return back into the first script, does it? Thank you, please include that explanation into the answer.

Comment: Added. There is a link on `call` also explaining its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Use pushd to save the current directory then use popd to restore it after you run the other cmd file.

```
pushd .
call C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\wl_server\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd 
popd
```

Good thing about pushd/popd is they work even if the other batch file changes the working directory to a directory on another drive.

Comment: Sorry, those pop/push are excessive. call+ cd is enough. But thank you.